# CSS hover on dot to reveal image - not hovering on image

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a merchandising page where there will be several products photoshopped onto the background image.  I want customers to be able to hover on a dot positioned on the product to reveal it's information and contain a link similar to http://www.wineenthusiast.com/custom-cellars/ but I want to do it in pure CSS.  I only want the info and link to appear when a user hovers on the dot and then on the containing div.  The issue I keep running into is that since both elements are contained in the same div, the corresponding image is displayed.  This will be too messy when there are 15 products on this page.  Still a noob coder so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakvisualdesign/hvb77m8L/2/

and the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div class="base">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/steinersports/CMS+Pages/Yankees+Man+Cave/background.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="pop-container-a">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/steinersports/CMS+Pages/Yankees+Man+Cave/background.jpg">
    <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:
        #container {
    position:relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

```
.base {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}

#container.pop-container-a img { 
position: absolute;
}

.dot {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
z-index: 10;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.pop-container-a img { 
position:absolute;
opacity: 0;
width: 150px;
transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.pop-container-a:hover .dot, .pop-container-a:hover img { 
opacity: 1;
}

.pop-container-a {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 50px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please write your javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed that up for you: http://jsfiddle.net/hvb77m8L/3/

The trick is using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` to allow hovering on the dot to affect the image next to it. So, this:

```css
.pop-container-a:hover .dot, .pop-container-a:hover img { 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

becomes this:

```css
.dot:hover + img { 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Edit:** and since that selects an element immediately *following* the targeted one, also note that I changed this:

```
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/steinersports/CMS+Pages/Yankees+Man+Cave/background.jpg">
    <div class="dot"></div>
```

to this:

```
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/steinersports/CMS+Pages/Yankees+Man+Cave/background.jpg">
```

**Edit 2:** To make the images remain when hovered on, you can make them inactive by default by setting their width to 0:

```
.pop-container-a img {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0; // in addition to being invisible, the image will not respond to hovering
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}
```

Then, when the dot is hovered, return the images to normal width and normal opacity:

```
.dot:hover + img {
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And when the image is in this state, it can now remain there with a hover effect:

```
.dot + img:hover {
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

A new fiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/hvb77m8L/6/

Comment: Thank you so much wavemode, that's perfect!

Comment: Another question: now when I want to hover on the hidden image, it disappears.  Is there anything else that I can do so that it stays?  Thanks.